# Convert string to array in Java?

Tags: java

I have a string which has the values like this (format is the same):

```
name:xxx
occupation:yyy
phone:zzz
```

I want to convert this into an array and get the occupation value using indexes.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you would use Java's `split()` function:

```
String str = "Name:Glenn Occupation:Code_Monkey";

String[] temp = str.split(" ");
String[] name = temp[0].split(":");
String[] occupation = temp[1].split(":");
```

The resultant values would be:

```
name[0] - Name
name[1] - Glenn

occupation[0] - Occupation
occupation[1] - Code_Monkey
```

Comment: What in case Name:Glenn Nelson(inclusive of spaces)

Comment: Well that would change the playing field. He asked for it in the format of xxx:xxx yyy:yyy not xxx:xx x yyy:y yy.

Comment: am not declaring the String statically, am storing it dynamically, the values comes like one below the other (like Name:Glenn and then in the new line Occupation:Code_Monkey)...??????????

Comment: I'm just giving you the underlying principal of what you were asking for. Doing it dynamically depends on your program's IO.

Answer (score 1):

Read about Split functnio. You can split your text by " " and then by ":"

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using String's [split function](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: The values comes dynamically, iam storing in a String my question is how to convert that String values into an array and get the value?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to convert to a property Map rather than an array.

e.g.

```
String text = "name:xxx occupation:yyy phone:zzz";
Map<String, String> properties = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
for(String keyValue: text.trim().split(" +")) {
   String[] parts = keyValue.split(":", 2);
   properties.put(parts[0], parts[1]);
}
String name = properties.get("name"); // equals xxx
```

This approach allows your values to be in any order.  If a key is missing, the get() will return null.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only interested in the occupation value, you could do:

```
String s = "name:xxx occupation:yyy phone:zzz";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*occupation:(\\S+).*");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
if (matcher.matches()){
    String occupation = matcher.group(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str = "name:xxx occupation:yyy phone:zzz
    name:xx1 occupation:yy3 phone:zz3
    name:xx2 occupation:yy1 phone:zz2"

name[0] = str.subtsring(str.indexAt("name:")+"name:".length,str.length-str.indexAt("occupation:"))
occupation[0] = str.subtsring(str.indexAt("occupation:"),str.length-str.indexAt("phone:"))
phone[0] = str.subtsring(str.indexAt("phone:"),str.length-str.indexAt("occupation:"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution:

```
String[] temp= objValue.split("\n");
String[] temp1 = temp[1].split(":");
String Value = temp1[1].toString();
System.out.println(value);
```